# Bracket Depth List

Tags: code-golf, array, balanced-string, ragged-list

### Challenge

Your challenge is simple, calculate the depth of each matching brackets in the given input e.g. `(()()(()))`->`[[1,1,[1]]]`, and output it in the form of a list/array/string representation

### Explanation:

For every bracket in the input, you have to count how many nested brackets there are for that part of the input e.g. `()` has 1 depth

Although if find a bracket of depth 2 e.g. `(())`, a list `[]` is formed from the 1st bracket `(  )` has to be added to the output with the 2nd bracket, `()` of depth 1 inside that list

### Test cases:

```
() -> [1]
[[][]] -> [[1,1]]
{}{}{{}}{{{}}} -> [1,1,[1],[[1]]
```

### Others

You may assume that there are only lists and `1`'s will be in the required output

For the output, you are allowed to output the depth as a list/array, or as a string representation e.g. `1 1 [1]` for `()()(())`

You can output it in other ways, but the depth of the brackets must be distinguishable from each other.

Your answer should be able to handle one type of bracket (one of `()`, `[]`, or `{}`), at your choice.

You may assume that input is balanced and only uses the type of bracket you chose.

Comment: "You may assume only parentheses will appear in the input"... "you may assume that other types of brackets are allowed". Does this mean that any solution only needs to accept one variety of bracket, but is free to choose which? Also, how does indexing figure into this? The challenge appears to just be replace immediate pairs of brackets with `1`, then add some (unspecified?) separators.

Comment: added the explanation and changed accordingly

Comment: If I output as a string, must I have a separator between elements (i.e. can I output "11[1]" instead of "1 1 [1]"?)

Comment: u must have a separator between elements its supposed to be distuingisible. list is best but if u have to use spaces

Comment: Are `[]` `()` `{}` all the valid brackets, or might there be others (i.e. `<>`)? Can we assume the input will be balanced?

Comment: [] () {} are all the valid brackets and u can assume the input has 1 type of bracket at any one time

Comment: I really can't tell if we may choose a bracket type or if we need to handle all three. (I see that the input won't have a mix of bracket types). If we must handle all three then may we output using the input's bracket type - for example, like [this](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/f8@HOBQ93Ltb1zn@4c@3DHYv@P9y95XD7o6Y1kf//a2hyRUfHRsfGclXXAmF1LRADiVoA)?

Comment: "e.g. `1 1 [1]` for `()()(())`" - this also seems to imply that we may exclude the outermost pair of brackets in our output - for example, like [this](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/f8@HOBQ93Ltb1zn@4c9r/h7u3HG5/1LQm8v9/DU2u6OjY6NhYrupaIKyuBWIgUQsUBQoDxSFkbCwA), was that intentional or is that an acceptable form of output?

Comment: Must `]` and `[` also be separated from each other or would `[1,1,[1][[1]]` be an acceptable output for your third test case? ...and also `[1,1[1][[1]]`?

Comment: What is a bracket in this challenge?  I would usually just infer that a bracket is a single character, but There are far fewer numbers in the output than there are characters in the input, so something else is clearly meant.

Comment: you caculate the depth so basically take every []->1 and every nested bracket [[]]->[1]

Answer (score 4):

## [Python](https://www.python.org/), <s>236</s> 155 bytes

```python
def r(o):
 v="[";s=a=n=0
 for c in o:
  if c=="(":
   if s<1:a=n+1
   s+=1
  else:
   s-=1
   if a==n:v+="1,"
   elif s<1:v+=r(o[a:n])
  n+=1
 return v+"]"
```

Is this a good solution? No. But I don't think there'll be another answer here soon, and I'm very new to codegolf so I thought I might try my luck here :p

[Attmpt this online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=NU87CsMwDN17CqHJxg00W3Grk4QMIbVpIMjBTgI9S5Ys7SF6k96mctIiJPH0nn7La3iM98Dr-pxGX5w_y815iCpoe4CZsMJLooaYTgfwIUILHUMQDjoPLREqzCCjdC2tKE2ZcTKUs-uT2_hUbDjrGiK2syEsj5hLrv81S00WV43lWgvB24joxikyzAZr3E98D7HjUUWFSospLS5Bo9a74P_LFw)

Comment: [Welcome to Code Golf](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/20861), and nice first answer! Be sure to check out our [Tips for Golfing in Python](/q/54) page for ways you may be able to golf your code! For example, you can remove many of the spaces: https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=NY9RCoMwDIbfPUXIU0sn6NvQ5STiQ3EtE1yUtgo7y15ksB1iN9lt1upGSMKX_IE_99d0C5eR1_U5B5sfP4-zseDEKKsMFsIGa09FranIwI4O-AAd9AyG56txOphdCb2FjggFJkjkT2WliVWZ2CtK3QzebHufb5x0moirRRGWB0wjM_yO4yzaaHTFrczAmTA7hkVhi7vT9-R6DsIJFDKGkDFjkSjlLvi_9AU

Comment: [138](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=NY4xCsMwDEX3nEJ4sgmBeitOdRLjwSQ2DRQ52E6gSw_QK3TJ0h6iN-ltKhqKkAb996X_eM3Xek60bc-lxu74uY8hQpZJmQZWtK4v6JHw0EBMGQaYCBJLMEUYEIUUxmM5aU9jd2Mpg-9Li5qJcCnBlA51v7Z8AwkYstoxsxssv7HekFO8s44t9HPmUJdMsO6J3nOeqMoshVRcUnHzUEKpHfhH_wI)

Comment: if it's allowed to use generators of generators, [131](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=NVA7bsMwDN19CsKT1NZBvRVKOfcC2QQPbEyhAqwPJHXwkqXH6JIluVNuUzZuQZAAH9_jI_h9zWv7SPF8vnw2N7zcvmZ2UFTSpoOKhBGfO3CpwBF8hCQoeAdHxF71hrC-jhTn4SSjArSvjzgKg5fKpg447lfPywyupACEGEHIdpyEuwmtOFkycdKC2UmkUTb8nRJ8yKk0aGvm2jEgLBTeZwIyd0yRBsRtvHvjyIVaKgdpf23APgTKip-A9HS_rsvFx6ZYFdUrLaG0pBTdS26m_3_4AQ)